# RxJS sequential operations

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm using RxJS to communicate with Database and I'm trying to send complex composite object. Our API let us to inject one element at time (i.e. POST will not handle array in body)
Consider following object, where `mainField` & `subFields` will be separate tables entities in DB:

```
OBJ = {
      'mainField': 'Main content'
      'subFields': [ 'obj1','obj2','obj3' ]
    }
```

The requirements are:

1. `mainField` must be transmitted first, response object will be supplied with reference ID, that `subFields` will use
2. Each element of `subFields` must be transmitted as single, and when response will arrive, another can be requested

Conceptually procedure for me looks something like this (`send` function is a simplification that accepts anything and return observable of this type):

```
send(OBJ.mainField) /* This will return Observable of mainField */
.flatMap(res => {
   OBJ.subFields.forEach(sub => {
     sub.id = res.id
   })
   Obervable.of(OBJ.subFields)
})
.flatMap(subField => {
  send(subField )
})
```

I believe there is a better way to do this (i.e. brake apart array, emit series of observables and wait untill they complete in order, then move on). I'd be grateful for any suggestions

Answer (score 3):

You can use `concat` that makes sure the Observables are subscribed in order only after the previous one completed.

```
Observable.of(OBJ) // or whatever...
  .concatMap(obj => {
    const mainField$ = send(obj.mainField);
    // the `concat()` subscribes to each Observable in order
    const subFields$ = Observable.concat(obj.subFields.map(field => send(obj.mainField)));

    // start processing `subFields$` after `mainField$` completed
    return mainField$.concat(subFields$);
  })
  .subscribe(() => console.log('All done'));
```

If you're not using `Observable.of(OBJ)` in you use-case you can use `send(obj.mainField)` instead like you did.